# Perceptron and Multilayer perceptron with 1 hidden node for solving XOR

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I am playing with Torch7 these days.

Today, I implemented Perceptron and Multilayer perceptorn (MLP) for solving XOR.

And as expected, MLP works well on XOR and Perceptron is not.

But I was curious what is the result if the number of hidden nodes is one.

I expected the result of MLP might be the same with Perceptorn because it has only 1 hidden node.

But interestingly, MLP was better then Percentron.

More detail, Perceptron get 0.25 error (as expected) but MLP with 1 hidden node get approximately 0.16 error.

I thought that one hidden node acts as one line in a problem space.

So, if there is only one hidden node, it could be the same with Perceptron.

But this result told me I was wrong.

Now, I want to know why MLP with 1 hidden node is better than Perceptron.

Please teach me why this result happened.

Thank you very much.

The following is the Perceptron code:

```
-- perceptron

require 'nn'

-- data
data = torch.Tensor({ {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1} })
-- target
target = torch.Tensor({ 0, 1, 1, 0 })

-- model
perceptron = nn.Linear(2, 1)
-- loss function
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()

-- training
for i = 1, 10000 do
   -- set gradients to zero
   perceptron:zeroGradParameters()
   -- compute output
   output = perceptron:forward(data)
   -- compute loss
   loss = criterion:forward(output, target)
   -- compute gradients w.r.t. output
   dldo = criterion:backward(output, target)
   -- compute gradients w.r.t. parameters
   perceptron:backward(data,dldo)
   -- gradient descent with learningRate = 0.1
   perceptron:updateParameters(0.1)
   print(loss)
end
```

And the following is the MLP with 1 hidden node code:

```
-- multilayer perceptron

require 'nn'

-- data
data = torch.Tensor({ {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1} })
-- target
target = torch.Tensor({ 0, 1, 1, 0 })

-- model
multilayer = nn.Sequential()
inputs = 2; outputs = 1; HUs = 1;
multilayer:add(nn.Linear(inputs, HUs))
multilayer:add(nn.Tanh())
multilayer:add(nn.Linear(HUs, outputs))
-- loss function
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()

-- training
for i = 1, 10000 do
   -- set gradients to zero
   multilayer:zeroGradParameters()
   -- compute output
   output = multilayer:forward(data)
   -- compute loss
   loss = criterion:forward(output, target)
   -- compute gradients w.r.t. output
   dldo = criterion:backward(output, target)
   -- compute gradients w.r.t. parameters
   multilayer:backward(data,dldo)
   -- gradient descent with learningRate = 0.1
   multilayer:updateParameters(0.1)
   print(loss)
end
```

Comment: please verify that the same happens with **different learning rates**. You should find a learning rate where perceptron gets analogous error. In terms of hypothesis modeled, these models are equivalent, however they follow different path in the hypotheses space due to different scaling of values/gradients due to the existance of activation function.

Comment: What do you mean by that you expected error on a 0.25 level?